# Trying to run jupyter-notebook on MacOs 13.3.1 (a) with python 3.9: ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+

Tags: jupyter-notebook, openssl, importerror, libressl

I just installed jupyter notebook via "pip3 install jupyterlab"
I added the install directory to my path (/Users//Library/Python/3.9/bin)

python version:
Python 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023, 20:16:38)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin

pip version: 23.1.2

jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.13.2
ipykernel        : 6.22.0
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.5.0
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.7.4
nbconvert        : 7.3.1
nbformat         : 5.8.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0

I can start jupyter-notebook, but when I try to run an import command (like "import openai") I get the following error:

"ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with LibreSSL 2.8.3. See: [https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168"](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168%22)

I don't really understand this.
"which openssl" points me to /usr/bin/openssl
and /usr/bin/openssl version
returns LibreSSL 3.3.6

I also did some googeling and looked up https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168, but I don't find a solution to my problem.

Would be thankful if someone could me point in the right direction.. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue and [this](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6432#issuecomment-1535149114) worked for me. I installed the desired version using

```
pip3 install "urllib3 <=1.26.15"
```

Comment: thank you. After looking more closely I saw that jupyter is still using python 3.9 - I'll have to do some research how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it works now since i upgraded to Python 3.11.

You can try with pipenv :

```
pipenv install --python 3.11
```

Comment: thank you. After looking more closely I saw that jupyter is still using python 3.9 - I'll have to do some research how to fix this